# variable hidden within a text

Tags: r

I would like to ask if there is a way to see a variable hidden within a text.

if I run

```
k <- eval(expression(v <- 1))
```

then I get v equal to 1.

But how does it work if I have

```
k <- "v <- 1"
```

Thank you, in advance

Comment: right now `v` is not a variable.  It's part of a string.  What is it you want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `parse(text=k)` to create an expression, then evaluate it:

```
eval(parse(text=k))
v
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `eval` and `evalq` commands if you're wanting to evaluate the code.

If you just want to find any string before an `<-` operator, I suppose you could use something like:

```
regexpr("(.*)[\\s]*<-", "a <- 1", perl=TRUE)
```

which would return the start index of the variable name, or -1 if there isn't one. You could extract it by using the `substr` command, if you just wanted the variable name.